# isin pandas doesn't show all values in dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am using the Amazon database for my research where I want to select the 100 most rated items. So first I have counted the values of the itemID's (asin)

```
data = amazon_data_parse('data/reviews_Movies_and_TV_5.json.gz')
unique, counts = np.unique(data['asin'], return_counts=True)
test = np.asarray((unique, counts)).T
test.sort(axis=1)
```

which gives:

```
array([[5, '0005019281'],
       [5, '0005119367'],
       [5, '0307141985'],
       ..., 
       [1974, 'B00LG7VVPO'],
       [2110, 'B00LH9ROKM'],
       [2213, 'B00LT1JHLW']], dtype=object)
```

It is clearly to see that there must be at least 6.000 rows selected. But if I run:

```
a= test[49952:50054,1]
a = a.tolist()
test2 = data[data.asin.isin(a)]
```

It only selects 2000 rows from the dataset. I already have tried multiple thing, like only filter on one asin but it doesn't just seem to work. Can someone please help? If there is a better option to get a dataframe with the rows of the 100 most frequent values in asin column I would be glad too.

Comment: When you execute: `a= test[49952:50054,1]` what's in a?

Comment: A list of values of the asin column

Comment: Looks like your sorting doesn't work the way you think. Try `test.sort(axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, had to change the sorting line to:

```
test = test[test[:,1].argsort()]
```

Comment: `test.sort(axis=0)` should do the exact same thing.